# How to format this in php side

Tags: php

I want to output like this

```
      [
          ['Alice', 'Mike'],
          ['Bob', 'Jim'],
          ['Carol', 'Bob']
      ]
```

but i could not get the format

here is my code

```
  $cmd = $this->connection->prepare('SELECT emp,manager from department');
  $cmd->execute();
  $records = $cmd->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  foreach($records as $row) {

     $rowdata=$row;


  }


  $return_data = array($rowdata);


  echo json_encode($return_data);
```

Thank you in advance

**update: Answer**

```
 $rowdata=array_values($row);
```

Thank you @Ja͢ck

Comment: `$rowdata[] = array_values($row);`

Comment: What output do you get after running you code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $records = $cmd->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
 foreach($records as $row) {    
     $rowdata[] = array_values($row);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `<pre>` tags around the array and use `print_r()` to print it, it will come out as very readable.

Answer (score 0):

Update :

```
$cmd = $this->connection->prepare('SELECT emp,manager from department');
$cmd->execute();
$records = $cmd->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$rowdata=array();

foreach($records as $record) {
    $rowdata[] = array($record->em.','.$record->manager);      
}

$return_data = $rowdata;
echo json_encode($return_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can check

```
foreach($records as $row) {
    $rowdata[]=$row;
}

$return_value=array_chunk($rowdata,2);
echo json_encode($return_value);
```